# Is it possible to modify a web page as it's loading?

Tags: dhtml

I have a Perl script that generates a web page. It takes a non-trivial amount of time to run. I would like to be able to render a complete HTML table to the user so they know what results to expect, but fill in the details slowly as the Perl script generates them.

What approach should I be taking here?

My initial assumption was that I would be able to assign an ID to my various table data elements and then adjust their innerHTML properties as and when I got the results in. But it doesn't seem like I can perform such manipulations whilst the page is still loading.

Comment: Can you give an example that shows that you can't do these innerHTML manipulations? It would seem to me that it should work fine, as long as you structure the HTML properly (that is, provide enough up front that the browser can confidently start rendering), and assign default initial values to the elements where you will put the data.

Answer (score 3):

There's no consistantly reliable way to modify a web page as it's loading.

You can create the effect by initially loading a compact loading page, and then loading the rest of the content via AJAX calls back to the server to get the individual components.

You can then load those components as your AJAX calls are completed.

**EDIT**

As the comments have pointed out...while this would achieve the results you want, it's a terrible idea.

Search Engine Indexing being the primary reason. You're also relying on Javascript to do a lot of heavy lifting...and it might not always be enabled.

Comment: for completeness you should mention why this would be a very bad idea (i.e. google problems, JS dependency, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to progressively load the data via AJAX.  You would need to do something like this:

- Load the webpage

  3. Using javascript, query the webserver for table values
  4. Populate table with received values
  5. Loop until table filled

Obviously this solution presents problems if the data is meant to be crawled.  Since crawlers don't take into account dynamic data via javascript.

The other issue to consider is usability.  Web Users are not used to this type of progressive loading, so informing them that the data is still being loaded would be very important.  Also some type of *accurate* progress bar would provide good usability.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, AJAX is probably the way to go.

Create a basic HTML page with an empty div to hold your data, then using repeating AJAX calls, fill in the div.

This page describes how to do this:
[link text](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/web/realtime.html#text)